# Масштабирование сайта bootstrap @media

Tags: масштабирование, bootstrap, css

Привет.

Скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно указать масштабирование для определенных девайсов bootstrap?
Например:

```
 @media (min-width: 1200) { 
...
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
width: 80%; (от размера 1200)
}
```

Хотелось бы добиться эффекта масштабирования страницы в браузере (когда ctrl+ ctrl-), при уменьшении масштаба на 80%, сайт на экране ноута смотрится как нужно. Можно ли это сделать короткой записью или нужно прописывать все параметры классам?

Comment: @Alexander Masan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае нужно копать в сторону понятия "zoom сайта", CSS media queries и масштабирование сайта - это не то. Хотя если вы делали всё с помощью bootstrap, то zoom должен быть как нужно настроен.